# Split string array in Java using regex

Tags: java, arrays, regex, split

I'm trying to split this string :

> aba(2)bb(52)gc(4)d(2)fe(14)f(6)g(8)h(4)5(6)

so it looks like this array :

> [ a, b, a(2), b, b(52), g, c(4), d(2), f, e(14), f(6), g(8) ]

Here are the rules, it can accept letters **a to g**, it can be a letter alone but if there is parentheses following it, it has to include them and its content. The content of the parentheses **must be a numeric value**.

This is what I tried :

```
content = "aba(2)bb(52)gc(4)d(2)fe(14)f(6)g(8)h(4)5(6)";
        a = content.split("[a-g]|[a-g]\\([0-9]*\\)");
        for (String s:
             a) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

And here's the output

> (2)
>
> (52)
>
> (4) (2)
>
> (14) (6) (8)h(4)5(6)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to match these substrings:

```
String content = "aba(2)bb(52)gc(4)d(2)fe(14)f(6)g(8)h(4)5(6)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-g](?:\\(\\d+\\))?");
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
while (matcher.find()){
    res.add(matcher.group(0)); 
} 
System.out.println(res);
```

Output:

```
[a, b, a(2), b, b(52), g, c(4), d(2), f, e(14), f(6), g(8)]
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/D8xSmE) and a [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/NYx10Q/1).

**Pattern details**

- `[a-g]` - a letter from `a` to `g`
- `(?:\(\d+\))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `\)` - a `)` char.

Comment: Thank you it works well. Also thanks for the details, I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the split method only, here is an approach you could follow too,

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        String content = "aba(2)bb(52)gc(4)d(2)fe(14)f(6)g(8)h(4)5(6)";
        String[] a = content.replaceAll("[a-g](\\([0-9]*\\))?|[a-g]", "$0:").split(":");
        // $0 is the string which matched the regex

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

   }

}
```

Regex : `[a-g](\\([0-9]*\\))?|[a-g]` matches the strings you want to match with (i.e a, b, a(5) and so on)

Using this regex I first replace those strings with their appended versions (appended with :). Later, I split the string using the split method.

Output of the above code is,

```
[a, b, a(2), b, b(52), g, c(4), d(2), f, e(14), f(6), g(8), h(4)5(6)]
```

NOTE: This approach would only work with a delimiter that is known to not be present in the input string. For example, I chose a colon because I assumed it won't be a part of the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Split is the wrong approach for this, as it is hard to eliminate wrong entries.

Just "match", whatever is valid and process the result array of found matches:

```
[a-g](?:\(\d+\))?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ZF5Nv5Dvd7RXJm_N)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following regex: `[a-g](\(.*?\))?`

- `[a-g]`: letters from a to g required
- `(\(.*?\))?`: any amout of characters between `(` and `)`, matching as as few times as possible

You can view the expected output [here](https://regex101.com/r/Agapxl/1).

This answer is based upon `Pattern`, an example:

```
String input = "aba(2)bb(52)gc(4)d(2)fe(14)f(6)g(8)h(4)5(6)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-g](?:\\(\\d+\\))?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    tokens.add(matcher.group());
}

tokens.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Resulting output:

```
a
b
a(2)
b
b(52)
g
c(4)
d(2)
f
e(14)
f(6)
g(8)
```

**Edit:** Using `[a-g](?:\((.*?)\))?` you can also easily extract the inner value of a bracket:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    tokens.add(matcher.group());
    tokens.add(matcher.group(1)); // the inner value or null if no () are present 
}
```

Comment: It does match the required pattern ... but this won't work with split

Comment: @mettleap You are right, i added more details to describe how i solved the problem. Thanks for pointing out!